# AsyncTask not working properly

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Here is my problem. I have noticed that my `AsyncTask` does not work properly. What I mean is, even if I run this code:

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    progress.setText(values[0] + "%");
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    for (i = 0; i <= 100; ++i) {
        publishProgress(i);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("progress", i + "");

    }
    return null;
}
```

it does not seem to do antything at all and after 5 seconds (or even more) my progress alomost instantly goes from 0 to 100%, even though it should wait for 10ms between every call of publishProgress(). Is it something that I'm missing?

Comment: increase your sleep to 100 ms

Comment: It still waits for a long time before the progress changes.

Comment: Are you calling `execute()` or `get()`?

Comment: I'm calling execute();

Comment: @ColdFire 100 times 10 ms is 1 second.

Comment: My problem is not how long it takes for my progress to go from 0-100%, it is how long it taske for my progress to actually start. What I mean is it takes for about 5 seconds before my progress goes from 0-1% and then it changes with a constant delay of 10ms.

Comment: Your code is working perfect i tried it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think is a thread problem , because AsyncTask automatically creates a new Thread for you, so everything you do in doInBackground() is on another thread.
So start "sleep" onPreExecute() and finish onPostExecute()

Comment: Even if I completly remove Thread.sleep() from doInBackground, it still takes about 5 seconds before onProgressUpdate() seems to be called.

Comment: Set a start of your progress onPreExecute() and than update it on onProgressUpdate() or start Thread.sleep(10) onPreExecute()

Answer (score 0):

You called  `Thread.sleep(10);` for 10ms which which cause 100*10 = 100ms(1 second). It will complete all progress. It cause to full progress in very short duration.

You can increase `Thread.sleep(1000)` If you want to see clearly progress or you can print a Log for System.currentTimeInMillis() in onProgressUpdate to see the progress.

Make sure you have called asyncTask.execute() for running the AsyncTask.